# Stack Overflow for Teams? How does it work?

Tags: discussion

Today I realized that there seems to be a few feature of the StackExchange website, i.e., it seems that we can form teams to share and discuss topics in specific fields. To be honest, I do not know how does that work? For instance: (i) How can we see the existing teams (i.e., teams that have already been formed) and how to join an existing team? (ii) If I want to form a team for studying areas of my personal interest, how can I invite some other people to join ? My questions are definitely not exhaustive, and thanks for your help!

Comment: This is the Mathematics meta. Did you mean to ask this on Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: Last time I checked, it was meant only for a business.  I looked into it for the possibility of using it for some group project here on Math.SE.

Comment: @AsafKaragila sorry this is the only place that I can think of to ask this type of question

Comment: The left-hand menu bar now has a TEAMS section added to it, so it looks like there is now something there that is not directly intended for business.

Comment: @postmortes:  Indeed it does allow me to create a free StackOverflow Team, which I have called "Just the Factors".  I will be inviting (up to 49) colleagues to join that private team, loosely focused on setting up desktop/server software to solve factorization problems and related algorithms.  Ping me if you are interested.

Comment: @hardmath that sounds quite interesting!  I have no free time at the moment to try such an experiment myself, but I hope it proves useful for you :)

Comment: @hardmath wants to break RSA...amirite? xD

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the interests of saving people a tiny amount of effort looking on Stack Overflow, this post: [Stack Overflow for Teams is now free for up to 50 users, forever](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362203/stack-overflow-for-teams-is-now-free-for-up-to-50-users-forever) seems to explain the changes and provide other links regarding them.

Answer (score 7):

**(i) How can we see the existing teams (i.e., teams that have already been formed) and how to join an existing team?**

These Teams are essentially private SE Communities, with the same Q&A format especially as StackOverflow (a bit more dark mode and WYSIWYG than Math.SE).  So I doubt there is any way to "see the existing teams".

**(ii) If I want to form a team for studying areas of my personal interest, how can I invite some other people to join?**

You can perhaps create your own team, as I did.  It picked up my credentials from my StackOverflow account, so you may find a different experience.  Once your team is created you will be able to invite team members based on submitting an email address for each one.  (I think the invitations expire in a week.)

Up to now certain chat rooms have served in this fashion, for studying areas of common interest.  The Teams environment is not "chatty" but meant to expose content useful for the group in a Q&A format.  I'd guess that some groups who find their combined efforts productive in chat will benefit from migrating to Teams, but that most will not.

Answer (score 7):

Just as a heads-up, it appears that MathJax is not enabled on any free team.

Perhaps it is an optional feature available only for upgraded (paid) teams, or one needs to request for it to be enabled on a per-team basis, but the latter seems overly optimistic to me, honestly.

In any case, I think the free Teams feature is less useful for members of this SE than for others.

---

As suggested in the comments, a workaround is to use @robjohn's [bookmarklets](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Erobjohn/math/mathjax.html) for rendering MathJax. Just be sure that you've turned on the "Markdown" option in the new Stacks editor: somehow the dollar-delimiters do not work well with newlines otherwise.

Comment: Does it work when you manually click on one of [these bookmarklets?](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html)

Comment: @CalvinKhor No, it doesn't work even with those bookmarklets. (That was actually the very next thing I tried after making a post there!) It seems that chat is a more convenient venue for hosting discussions than teams, and that's saying something.

Comment: For me the bookmarklet works! Great success :)

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks for the ping, I decided to give it another go and it worked, you're right! I'm not fully sure what was the issue before, but it seems that
`$$ <newline> e^{\iota \pi} + 1 = 0 <newline>$$`
doesn't work for some reason, but `$$e^{\iota pi} + 1 = 0$$` works.

Comment: Okay, now I think the funny interaction with the dollar-delimiters and newlines has to do with the new Stacks editor. Turning on the "Markdown" option fixes that.